# Is This VB.net Error A Hosting Environment Error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On a VB.net page, I am clicking an Edit Button on a DataGrid, when I get the below error.  I think this is a hosting environment issue for my hosting company to rectify, rather than an error in my script.  Would you agree?  Do you know what must be done on the server to rectify this type of error?  Thanks.

**-- Error Starts --**

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\244b2b37\c0134493\uploads\inzbg7lz.tmp'.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\244b2b37\c0134493\uploads\inzbg7lz.tmp'`.

**-- Error Ends --**

Comment: Look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934839

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck with this.  I don't really know why it would be looking for the file mentioned.  The script used to work OK, then it just stopped working, making me think it's the server environment that's the issue.

Comment: Would giving the stack trace help?

Comment: I am still totally stuck with this, here's the full error: